# Ajax Request cached on iOS AppCached

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, offline-caching

I have an HTML5 offline application doing the following things:

1. display a page
2. check manifest (according to specs)
3. perform an ajax request (using Prototype) to check if online.

I have the following issue ONLY on Mobile Safari iOS (not Safari, not Chrome, not Firefox):

- OK: Run scénario online
- OK: Run scénario offline (plane mode)
- OK: Stop the server OK
- KO: Restart the server

**The Ajax-Request is performed but hangs until timeout like if it was offline**

WorkAround

- OK: If I update the manifest the cache is refreshed
- OK: If I clean cache in iOS preferences
- KO: If I put a parameter in the ajax-request (like ?d={timemillis} )
- KO: The ajax request is in POST
- KO: The request has heades: Cache-Control: no-store and Pragma: no-cache
- KO: If I kill MobileSafari and reload
- KO: The NETWORK part of the manifest have expliclty the URL

So I do not know what to do:

- I can't clean mobile safari storage because it also clear localStorage
- I can't 'touch' the manifest file on the server
- I can't be sure my user will always be in "plane mode"

Question:

- Is there a way to force cache update ? (according to specs no)
- Is there a way to forbidden caching of Ajax Request ? (other than manifest)
- Is there any jsFiddle that demonstrate it works on iOS ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests it seems the MobileSafari on iOS is really buggy. My company decide to stop this Proof of Concept and wait for an improved version or a framework dealing with all bugs.